# How do you pass class as a key value pair of ASP.NET MVC htmlAttributes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like to pass the html input class attribute in ASP.NET MVC for my input box using Html.TextBox("FullName", null, new{**class**="grey-input"}). But I think I can use the "*class*" keyword.

How can I bypass this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yeh you need to use @class which allows you to use a reserved word.

```
Html.TextBox("FullName", null, new{@class="grey-input"})
```

So an example:

```
<%= Html.TextBox("Name","Andy",new{@class="Test"}) %>
```

Produces

```
<input class="Test" id="Name" name="Name" type="text" value="Andy" />
```

You could also create a custom Extension method for this also, but the above way is what I use.