# Provide value to htmlAttributes where keys are c# reserved keyword name in MVC view (e.g. css "class")

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc, keyword

Most of the Html helpers available in ASP.Net MVC have overloads with `object htmlAttributes`. This is used to provide additional attribute values for the outputted tags. One common usage for these `htmlAttributes` is to output css class names.
So for example lets take the following example:

```
@Html.TextBox("Title", string.Empty, new { class="css-class-name" })
```

Here we are trying to create a textbox with class i.e. `class="css-class-name"`.
Try the above code in your view and visual studio would show you an error saying "Expression Expected".

So the question is, how to provide htmlAttributes with their keys made up of c# reserved keywords like "class"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you pass class as a key value pair of ASP.NET MVC htmlAttributes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618354/how-do-you-pass-class-as-a-key-value-pair-of-asp-net-mvc-htmlattributes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prefix your key name, madeup of reserved keyword, with an at-the-rate symbol `@` (like below example):

```
@Html.TextBox("Title", string.Empty, new { @class="css-class-name" })
```

*Note: it is bad practice to use reserved keywords as variable or property names but sometimes you just have to use them (for e.g. the case of css "class" mentioned in the question)*

Comment: +1 for the note. I never use them in my C# code, only in razor files.